# Angular & Javascript, how read scope variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am blocked in a very simple html sample with angular! My problem is about a Chart, made by js fw in a separate `<script>` tag. How can I read there some Angular values defined in a scope?

```
<script>
    var isisApp = angular.module('isisApp', []);
    isisApp.controller('AccountListCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.sample = {'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Smith', 'age': 25, 'AccountType': 'Safekeeping',
            'address': {'street': 'Dorsstok', 'city': 'Erica'},
            'phone': [{'type': 'home', 'number': '+31591302900'}, {'type': 'mobile', 'number': '+31625299740'}, {'type': 'Business', 'number': '+43223627551'}],
            'account': [{'type': 'Bonds', 'value': '111111'}, {'type': 'Stocks', 'value': '$ 0625299740'}, {'type': 'Funds', 'value': '999990'}],
            'json_read_date': '4/12'
    };
 });
 </script>
```

then I have another  tag where I am trying to use this statement without success:

```
var test = $('[ng-controller="AccountListCtrl"]').scope().sample.json_read_date;
```

and, despite I included jquery (last stable version 1.2.13) before angular (last stable version) I get this error:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$('[ng-controller="AccountListCtrl"]').scope().sample.json_read_date') (16:17:07:686 | error, javascript)

I am inside the body where the controller is correctly setup , in fact all the other values work correctly!
I really don't know how unlock the situation, please could you help me?

Comment: Try `angular.element($('[ng-controller="AccountListCtrl"]')).scope()` or `angular.element($('[ng-controller="AccountListCtrl"]')[0]).scope()`

Comment: Why would you ever need a jquery selector like that? You can always just set up a directive which will have the scope or just do what you need in the controller. What are you trying to do with json_read_date because it seems like there is a better way. Please provide more info

Comment: What if you can use global variable and then set its value in controller